# Show JSON Info in UILabel

Tags: ios, json, weather-api

I am getting JSON from World Weather Online and I'm trying to show the temperature in Fahrenheit in a label but when I run it, that label shows (null). The JSON shows fine in the console so I know it is pulling the right data. Any ideas?

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
#define weatherURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=47129&format=json&num_of_days=5&date=today&key=37a5fj42xpyptvjgkhrx5rwu"]

#import "Weather.h"
#import "WeatherLocation.h"

@interface Weather ()

@end

@implementation Weather

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:weatherURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
    // parse out the JSON data
    NSError * error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSArray *weather = [json objectForKey:@"data"];

    NSLog(@"weather: %@", weather);

    NSArray *temp = [json objectForKey:@"temp_F"];

    NSDictionary *weatherConditions = [temp objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *tempF = [weatherConditions objectForKey:@"temp_F"];

    currentTemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tempF];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Result of `NSLog(@"weather: %@", weather);`

```
weather: {
    "current_condition" =     (
                {
            cloudcover = 50;
            humidity = 83;
            "observation_time" = "11:28 AM";
            precipMM = "0.0";
            pressure = 1016;
            "temp_C" = 22;
            "temp_F" = 72;
            visibility = 13;
            weatherCode = 116;
            weatherDesc =             (
                                {
                    value = "Partly Cloudy";
                }
            );
            weatherIconUrl =             (
                                {
                    value = "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png";
                }
            );
            winddir16Point = N;
            winddirDegree = 0;
            windspeedKmph = 0;
            windspeedMiles = 0;
        }
    );
    request =     (
                {
            query = 47129;
            type = Zipcode;
        }
    );
    weather =     (
                {
            date = "2013-09-09";
            precipMM = "0.0";
            tempMaxC = 35;
            tempMaxF = 95;
            tempMinC = 21;
            tempMinF = 69;
            weatherCode = 113;
            weatherDesc =             (
                                {
                    value = Sunny;
                }
            );
            weatherIconUrl =             (
                                {
                    value = "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png";
                }
            );
            winddir16Point = SSW;
            winddirDegree = 210;
            winddirection = SSW;
            windspeedKmph = 12;
            windspeedMiles = 7;
        }
    );
}
```

I was attempting to make this work with the code I posted.  If I use the weather array, the app crashes on `NSDictionary *weatherConditions = [weather objectAtIndex:0];` with `[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa158f70`

UPDATE:  I fixed the issue with it returning NULL for temp_F.

Here is the current code:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
    // parse out the JSON data
    NSError * error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", json);

    NSDictionary *data = [json objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSArray *currentConditions = [data objectForKey:@"current_condition"];
    NSDictionary *conditions = [currentConditions objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *icon = [data objectForKey:@"weatherIconUrl"];
    NSDictionary *weatherIcon = [icon objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *tempF = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\u00B0", [conditions objectForKey:@"temp_F"]];
    NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [weatherIcon objectForKey:@"value"]];
    NSURL *conditionIcon = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:conditionIcon];
    UIImage *conditionImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    NSLog(@"Image URL: %@", imageURL);
    conditionsImage.image = conditionImage;

    NSLog(@"temp_F: %@", tempF);

    currentTemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tempF];
    [currentTemp setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond" size:72.0]];
}
```

The only problem I'm having now is that the weatherIconUrl is returning NULL now and I'm not sure why.

Comment: I would set a breakpoint in your `fetchedData` method and make sure none of those NSArray's or NSDictionary's are nil (which usually boils down to a parsing error e.g. a incorrect key)

Comment: What do you mean "the JSON shows fine"?  Do you NSLog "temp" or "tempF" anywhere to know if they're correct?  (And one suspects that you've screwed something up because you've got two different keys named "temp_F".)  (Do some actual debugging!)

Comment: Guessing you either aren't interpreting the JSON correctly, or the currentTemp outlet isn't hooked up...

Comment: Show the output of the `NSLog(@"weather: %@", weather);` line.

Comment: @rmaddy I've added the output.

Comment: Uh, I'm confused.  You extract "weather" from "json" and print it, then you don't use "weather" anywhere.  Maybe you should print out "json".

Comment: You're looking for it (weatherIconURL) in the wrong place.  Please quit just randomly changing your code and actually THINK about how it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.  Here is the code.

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
    // parse out the JSON data
    NSError * error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", json);

    NSDictionary *data = [json objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSArray *currentConditions = [data objectForKey:@"current_condition"];
    NSDictionary *conditions = [currentConditions objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *icon = [conditions objectForKey:@"weatherIconUrl"];
    NSDictionary *weatherIcon = [icon objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *weatherDesc = [conditions objectForKey:@"weatherDesc"];
    NSDictionary *description = [weatherDesc objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *tempF = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\u00B0", [conditions objectForKey:@"temp_F"]];
    NSString *desc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [description objectForKey:@"value"]];
    NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [weatherIcon objectForKey:@"value"]];
    NSURL *conditionIcon = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:conditionIcon];
    UIImage *conditionImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    NSLog(@"Image URL: %@", imageURL);
    conditionsImage.image = conditionImage;

    NSLog(@"temp_F: %@", tempF);

    currentTemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tempF];
    [currentTemp setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond" size:72.0]];
    weatherDescription.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", desc];
    [weatherDescription setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond" size:36.0]];
}
```